# Can't use Jupyter NoteBook (Did not find path entry)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I try to run an `ipynb` file created in VS code I get the following error.
Tried:

1. Anaconda All update
2. Add User Environment variable path `C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\`, `C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\Scrits`

```
StdErr from ShellExec, Did not find path entry C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\bin Did not find path entry C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\bin for C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate myGUIvenv && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\NAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.108011\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/NAME/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.108011/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
```

Comment: I have the same problem. However, If I start _vscode_ from the _Anaconda Powershell Prompt_ (not from within the *Anaconda Naviagator*) I can run interactive code in the _ipython jupyter server_. There is def. something messed up somewhere..

Comment: I fixed this err. I changed interpreter path. From absolute path to relative path. The interpreter can be changed from the bottom left button (e.g. Python 3.7.3 64-bit)

Comment: "From absolute path to relative path" is not mandatory.

Comment: @ShinoharaTakuto Did yousolve the issue?